# Force refresh on data change in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently programing a website that displays weather, notes etc to a screen on a wall.
When you select widgets on a website, they are stored in a .json file.
When changes occur, this function is triggered on my node.js server:

```
fs.watchFile('__dirname/Data.json', (curr, prev) => {
    console.log("New changes on Data.json");
    fs.readFile('Data.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        widgets = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log (widgets);
    });
});
```

I want the screen on the wall to refresh the page as soon as there are changes on Data.json. Is there any way I could force the browser to do that?

Comment: How do you render your data ?

Comment: Look at Websockets or Socket.IO

Comment: @TGrif I use express so resp.render